# Using includes method to get a specific index from another array

Tags: javascript

Hey I want to use the includes method in a foreach loop to copy the elements in my numbers array with the help of my other array controlList lastly i want to push it to the controlListApproved array

As you can see in line 64 i tried but it gave me false all the time

```
var moreNumbers=[];
var controlList=[0, 4, 7, 9];
var controlListApproved=[];

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    moreNumbers[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-0))+0;
};
console.log(moreNumbers);

moreNumbers.forEach(function(item, index){

        console.log(moreNumbers.index=moreNumbers.includes(controlList));
    });
```

Comment: because `moreNumbers.index` is `undefined` all the time

Comment: also only used one = instead of 2 for comparison

Comment: I think you got your answer, but isn't `Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-0))+0 ` the same as `Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moreNumbers` does not have an `.index` property. If the array did have an `.index` property no comparison is made at `moreNumbers.index=<value>`, which is an assignment.

`controlList` is an `Array`, not a single element of an array.

`index` parameter of `.forEach()` callback does not appear to be necessary to be used to achieve the expected result.

`if` `controlList` `.includes()` `item` then `.push()` `item` to `controlListApproved`.

```
moreNumbers.forEach(function(item, index){
  if (controlList.includes(item)) {
    controlListApproved.push(item)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I perfectly understand what you're trying to do, but this might be your answer:

```
var moreNumbers=[];
var controlList=[0, 4, 7, 9];

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    moreNumbers[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-0))+0;
};
console.log(moreNumbers);

var controlListApproved = moreNumbers.filter(number => controlList.includes(number))
console.log(controlListApproved)
```

Answer (score 0):

Things that went wrong:

```
  moreNumbers.index
```

equals to

```
   moreNumbers["index"]
```

so you are actually trying to access a named property, instead you probably want to access the index that is stored in `index`:

```
 moreNumbers[index]
```

Now instead of checking wether `controlList` (which is an array of numbers) is inside of `moreNumbers` (which is an array of numbers, so it does not contain an array of numbers but just numbers), you probably want to check wether `item` is included in `controlList`:

```
 if(controlList.includes(item)) {
   //...
 }
```